# How can I change the database variable in .env file in github action?

Tags: laravel, github-actions

I want to run tests on a different database when there is a push request on the repo. I am using Laravel and have `.env` file with database values. I am unable to change database on the fly with GitHub actions? Is there a way to do so.

I have database defined as `DB_DATABASE` in .env file. I have done following in the github actions but it didnt work. Job failed. Sorry I am new to github actions.

```
name: PHP Composer

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
        with:
          php-version: '7.1.3'

      - name: Validate composer.json and composer.lock
        run: composer validate

      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '7.2'
          extensions: gmp, gd, intl, zip
      - run: composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-suggest
      - name: Run migrations
        env:
          DB_CONNECTION: mysql
          DB_DATABASE: ${{ 'db_laravel_test' }}
        run: yes | php artisan migrate
      - name: Execute tests via PHPUnit
        env:
          DB_CONNECTION: mysql
          DB_DATABASE: db_laravel_test
        run: vendor/bin/phpunit
      - name: Run test suite
        run: composer run-script test
      - name: Change back the database
        env:
          DB_DATABASE: ${{ 'db_laravel' }}
```

Comment: i guess github action have way to set `environmentgit` vairable  https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables

Comment: Sorry, I am new to github actions. I have updated my question with the script that I am running. It failed

Comment: Could you add the error (when the workflow fails) on the question as well Muhammad?

Comment: I resolved it by setting the other database environment variables in this file and also setting the APP_ENV to stage and APP_NAME in it.